# I have a question about creating a N x N matrix for polynomial approximation

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I want to solve for coefficients {c1,c2,...cn} based on the following relationship:
[image]

Where the N by N matrix B is a set of monomial basis {1,x,x^2,x^3,....x^n} and fa(x) is the approximation function. If I want to loop through n = [3,10,20,50] and given that `xj = 1/2*5-1/2*3*cos(j*pi/n)` (Chebyshev point distribution), how should I create such a matrix B using NumPy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the b's are functions, that would be powers of x

```
b0 = 1
b1 = x
b2 = x^2
b3 = x^3
...
```

And you are trying to find the best coefficients `c_n` to fit the function f(x)

You simply have to choose a set of x values.
Say, you want to do the approximation within the range -1 to +1. Choose values of xx such as x0 = -1.0, x1 = -0.9 , -0.8 , -0.7 ..., 0.9 , 1.0

`x = np.arange(-1,1, 0.1)`

Each line in B array are the x^n values for each of these xi values.

You have to decide to what power you want your polynomial. Perhaps the easiest way is to create a y space with the "exponent", example going from x^0 to x^5.
' y=np.arange(0,6) '

And then use the "meshgrid trick"

```
y_mg , x_mg = np.meshgrid (y, x)

#For each value of x_mg and y_mg, use numpy arithmetic
B = numpy.power(x_mg , y_mg)
```